# Loading a CommonJS file using Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, commonjs, webpack-2, path.js

I am trying to load the [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) library using Webpack 2. The library consists of a very simple CommonJS module - see [here](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/blob/master/src/store.js). However, I am running into multiple issues:

If I simply load it using `require('store.js');` it is picking up another `store.js` file that exists in my source folder.

To avoid a name clash, I aliased the file in my webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        storejs: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/store.js/store.js')
    }
},
```

Now I require the module as follows:

```
let localStore = require('storejs');
localStore.set('count', 2);
```

However now I get the following runtime error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: localStore.set is not a function
```

1. How do I make this work?
2. I don't like "requiring" the module. Is there a way to "import" the module instead? I am using ES6 imports everywhere else.

Comment: For 1. can you try `let localStore = require('storejs').default;` ?

Comment: With that change, I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"